# Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin has been blocked by CORS : The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, api, amazon-ec2

We have deployed our API's on amazon ec2 and we are using these API's on our frontend react.js.
We already have set the headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to '*' in backend

```
// Preflight API
static setPreflight = async () => {

    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('authData')}`
        }
    }
    await axios.options(`http://-------/preflight`, config)
}
```

when we call this function only once to set headers for preflight but we got this error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://ec2-13-125-149-247--------/preflight' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.

[image]

How to resolve this type of error on react.js?

Comment: Is the curly bracket in 'Authorization': `Bearer token}` a typo?

Comment: sorry there is a typo mistake, now we correct it. This is an auth token

Comment: kindly again review it

Comment: It is not up to React here, in the response header, so from the backend, you are receiving a duplicated header. It is visible from your image.